# MFC Ftp client in WinCE 5.0, afxinet not declare CFtpConnection function

Tags: mfc, ftp, client, windows-ce

Before use afxinet.h(CInternetSession,CFtpConnection) to

develope ftp client on wince, I use the CSocket to develope the

ftp client, for now I decide to use afxinet.h(CInternetSession,CFtpConnection),

in the pc site the CFtpConnection is be declare in afxinet.h,

but in the wince 5.0 the afxinet.h not support CFtpConnection,

why?  Would you give me some advice please
.
Otherwise, Can some one give me a CSocket example for WinCE 5.0 FTP Client

[pc side ftp client soft](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rh7oxe58dhd7c24/FTPClient_demo-CInternetSession.zip)

[wince side ftp client soft](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8u1t932ose0gvag/TerchyFTP.rar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of functions / classes were removed from Windows CE SDK because of memory requirements on this platform. Back when Windows CE 5.0 was designed, devices were produced with 64MB or fewer. From wiki (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_CE_5.0) you can read:

```
Memory footprint: The minimum footprint of Windows CE is 350 kilobytes.
```

You can still try porting MFC classes from desktop version to Windows CE, if you own Visual Studio 2005 license then in you compiler folders you will find full source code to `CFtpConnection`, I actually never used it but like most such classes in MFC it looks like thin wrapper around Win API functions. On my PC, files you are interested in are located here:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC\atlmfc\include\afxinet.h
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC\atlmfc\src\mfc\inet.cpp
```

as you will see, `CFtpConnection` makes calls like: `FtpDeleteFile`, `FtpRenameFile`, `FtpCreateDirectory`, `FtpRemoveDirectory`, `FtpPutFile`, ... which according to MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa452208.aspx

are available on Windows CE since version 2.12, so my suggestion is to either copy/pase those classes from desktop mfc sources, or code everything using Win API.